# Threading leading to crash (python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I am making a game and I need to run the function popup() and Maze() at the same time. I tried to do this with threading however it leads to a crash. I have tried many fixes but not found a solution.

```
def popup():
  threading.Timer(10.0, popup).start()
  Qscreen = Toplevel(screen)
  Qscreen.geometry("1920x1080")
  Qscreen.title("QUESTION")
  Label(Qscreen, text = MediumQ[random.randint(0,1)]).pack()

def Maze():
  app = MyApp()
  app.run()


def play():
    a = threading.Thread(target = popup)
    a.start()
    b = threading.Thread(target = Maze)
    b.start()
```

running this code always leads to a crash. Any fixes?

Comment: Please include details of the "crash" at least (error message etc). Are you using tkinter?

Comment: yes I am using Tkinter for the popup function and the Maze function is using panda3d. The crash leads to the entire program closing without leaving an error message in the idle shell however the problem window says this:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
@vaizki

Comment: You should initiate all GUI operations from a single thread in Tkinter. Use `.after()` on the main window for example to schedule the popup. Create separate threads only for background tasks which don't touch the GUI.

Comment: I need to run the Maze function and the popup function at the same time. What would you suggest for this? @vaizki